# How to overlap two divs in HTML (success message when logged in)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a little login page and when successfully logged in I want a massage to pop up (not an alert). I just want to have that message in the center of the page after I logged in.

Is there a way to implement that easily?

[picture of the website now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apzcu.png)

This little message window should be in the middle of the page

Comment: use position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%;

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your markup? What [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4665) have you done so far and how has it fallen short? Please don't just provide requirements and expect code as a result. Show your effort. Research "Modal Dialogs"

Comment: @Moritz - is this still an issue? Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call this a modal.

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close");

button.onclick = () => { overlay.style.display = "grid"; }
closeButton.onclick = () => { overlay.style.display = ""; }

window.onclick = (e) => {
  if (e.target === overlay) {
    overlay.style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.4);
}

.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 80vw;
  
}

.close {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
  <div class="modal">
    <button class="close">&times;</button>
    Congrats u logged in
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">login</button>
```

Comment: Although, in hindsight, even not knowing that this is a modal I think you might have found something when researching and trying on your own, so perhaps it was not a good idea to just give you the answer without asking for what you tried first